# Creating -* options, handling program arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program (in c) which will have 2 options, Read and Write an NFC at Block level and I compile/execute it from my Raspberry Pi (i.e.from terminal/bash).

What I'm trying to achieve in this program is something like this :

- **./ProgName -r /file.txt**

Read the NFC and send the output to file.txt

- **./ProgName -w /file.txt**

Copy to NFC what is written in file.txt

My question is : How do I create "-r" and "-w" options?

I don't know what are they called and how are they compiled/made/created. I have a vague idea that it's something concerning argc/argv but I'm not sure.

Comment: How is the question related to `bash`?

Comment: Read about the command line arguments. They are provided as arguments to [`main()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: Did you mean standard handling of args in C language? The take a look [there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm) 
You have `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`, `argc` gives you arguments length, in `argv` you can iterate over each arguments

Comment: As well as using argc and argv as in the answer, you could also use a library such as getopt to manage these for you. It may be overkill for this case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argc` is the number of command line parameters (including program call) and `*argv[]` is a pointer to the parameters.

In other words, considering the command line `./ProgName -r /file.txt`:

- `argc` is 3
- `argv[0]` is "./ProgName"
- `argv[1]` is "-r"
- `argv[2]` is "/file.txt"

A minimal program showing all command line parameters could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is what i was looking for !